# How to access cpanel from public ip of google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, cpanel, whm

i just created a Centos7 VM instance of google compute engine,  then i followed the instruction of installing cpanel&WHM so i had ssh into my instance using one of my desktop computers that doesn't have a UPS, so mid way the installation, power went off and my desktop went off as well, so i came back tried to reinstall but i ran into this erro`2018-12-31 16:20:58  701 (ERROR): The installation process found evidence that the following control panels were installed on this server:
2018-12-31 16:20:58  702 (ERROR): cPanel & WHM`

so i then i ran `/scripts/upcp --force` and the script seemed to have finished when i tried to run `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2087` i couldnt access the WHM login

but when i run `curl http://localhost:2087` it returns the html that actually is for the WHM login page, so how can i use the public ip to be able to access these ports used by cpanel or maybe if cpanel didnt install correctly, how can i fix it since the documentation and every one else says its not a good idea unistalling it and am new to these things.

Thanks in advance please some one help me

Comment: This question is not related to programming and such I would recommend you to post your question to appropriate forum such as [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) in your case which is meant to be for server and network related issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://x.x.x.x:2087 (whm)
https://x.x.x.x:2083 (cpanel user)

Please be sure that your individual CentOS VM and/or any other firewalls have those ports open or source IP allowed through.

Comment: i have tried runing the /scripts/configure_firewall_for_cpanel but all in vain then i opened the ports like `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=2087/tcp` but still get `The connection has timed out` in the browser. any more detailed solution is highly welcome.

Comment: you may need to ensure your Google Compute Engine console is allowing the required ports

Comment: Thank you very much actually i had to create another firewall rule and allowed both ports on my instance and it all works fine, thanks a bunch